# Error for installing npm install express-generator -g

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, express, npm

npm install express results in the following error.How to resolve this? There are already many duplicates of this question with INCORRECT answers, I'm sharing this with the below CORRECT answer to clear things up.

```
-bash-3.2$ npm install express-generator -g
npm WARN engine express-generator@4.13.1: wanted: {"node":">= 0.10"} (current: {"node":"v0.9.4-pre","npm":"1.4.16"})
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/bin/express'
npm ERR! error rolling back  express-generator@4.13.1 { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/bin/express'] errno: 3, code: 'EACCES', path: '/usr/local/bin/express' }
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/bin/express'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/bin/express'] errno: 3, code: 'EACCES', path: '/usr/local/bin/express' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.23.17-88.fc7
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "express-generator" "-g"
npm ERR! cwd /home/sukumar/www/nodejs/socialgrow
npm ERR! node -v v0.9.4-pre
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.16
npm ERR! path /usr/local/bin/express
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/bin/express'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/sukumar/www/nodejs/socialgrow/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Answer (score -1):

You can only install modules globally ( -g ) with root / admin. Run it as root and try again.

Comment: What's wrong with this answer? Please don't down vote without commenting.

Comment: you should check its  duplicate or not before  answering

Comment: @Manu for starters, it's incorrect. If you install `node` with `nvm` for example, you don't need (and it's even *not recommended*) to install things with root access. It all depends on where your node and npm are installed. Also, it is mentioned in one of the duplicates found in comments on the question.